# Как насписать свои ${} и element.find(), findAll из jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не хочу подключать весь jQuery.
Мне достаточно  ${} и elem.find()

Как написать это на javascript, алиас document.queryslector

Comment: [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) и [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.prototype.on = function(action, callback) {
  if(this !== '') {
    this.addEventListener(action, callback)
  }
};

Object.prototype.find = function(selector) {
  if(this !== '') {
    return this.querySelector(selector);
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};

Object.prototype.findAll = function(selector) {
  if(this !== '') {
    return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};

const find = function (selector, parent) {
  return (parent ? parent : document).querySelector(selector) || '';
};

const findAll = function (selector, parent) {
  return (parent ? parent : document).querySelectorAll(selector) || '';
};
    
    
    
 // Используем
let hamburger = find('.hamburger');
        
let span      = hamburger.find('span');
        
span.on('click', function() {
    
})
```

Comment: `let span.on(...` - интересный синтаксис :)

Comment: На самом деле `on` не равнозначен тому, что есть в *Jquery*, т.к. тут вешается слушатель на один конкретный элемент. И более того, не предусмотрена делегация. В то время как *Jquery* вешается слушатель на все элементы, указанные в селекторе и есть делегирование

Comment: `find` и `findAll` при неизетсном родителе не сработает. Например когда нужно цепочку построить `$(this).closest(selector).find(` - *Jquery* знает кто родитель...а тут нет....тут нужно всегда его знать....но чаще мы его не знаем и нужно делать `find` от элемента. который сам неопределен и ищется  "динамиески"

Comment: `this !== ''` это `true` для любого объекта